# Finding the indexes of an array

Tags: python, numpy

If i have an array like this

```
a = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],[False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
```

I tried np.random.choice but it doesnt work for 1_D arrays :(

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to loop through different indexes until you find a match

E.g.

```
import random
index_0 = 0
index_1 = 0
found = False
while not found:
   temp_i0 = random.randint(len(array))
   temp_i1 = random.randint(len(array[0]))
   if array[temp_i0][temp_i1]:
      index_0 = temp_i0
      index_1 = temp_i1
      found = True
```

Comment: This does not find a random index, as the OP requested.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood his question. Can you explain how this isn't a random index with the value true?

Comment: Ah whoops, my bad, I misread the algorithm. I think that rejection sampling isn't necessary here, but from a correctness standpoint there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit long winded, but serves its purpose nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

You show a 2d array:

```
In [581]: a = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],[False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],])

In [582]: a
Out[582]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
        False]])

In [583]: a.shape
Out[583]: (3, 10)
```

`np.nonzero` (or `np.where`) finds the indices of the `True` elements:

```
In [584]: np.nonzero(a)
Out[584]: (array([2, 2], dtype=int64), array([3, 4], dtype=int64))
```

That's a tuple of arrays.  It can be used for indexing as in:

```
In [585]: a[_]
Out[585]: array([ True,  True])
```

Read its docs